# How to receive an image on a dart server and store it?

Tags: flutter, dart

so basically i am sending an image (formdata) from client to a dart server. My handler function is something like this:

```
FutureOr<Response> _store(Request request) async {
  try {
    return Response.ok(jsonEncode('ok'));
  } catch (e) {
    return Response.internalServerError();
  }
}
```

I have tried many things including:

```
FutureOr<Response> _store(
    ModularArguments arguments, Injector injector, Request request) async {
  final contentType = request.headers['content-type'];
  if (contentType == null) {
    return Response(400, body: 'Missing content-type');
  }

  final mediaType = MediaType.parse(contentType);
  if (mediaType.mimeType != 'multipart/form-data') {
    return Response(400, body: 'Invalid content-type');
  }

  final boundary = mediaType.parameters['boundary'];
  if (boundary == null) {
    return Response(400, body: 'Missing boundary');
  }

  final payload = request.read();
  final parts = MimeMultipartTransformer(boundary).bind(payload);

  final partsIterator = StreamIterator(parts);
  while (await partsIterator.moveNext()) {
    final part = partsIterator.current;

    final file = File('.upload/newImgFile.png');
    if (await file.exists()) {
      await file.delete();
    }
    final chunksIterator = StreamIterator(part);
    while (await chunksIterator.moveNext()) {
      final chunk = chunksIterator.current;
      await file.writeAsBytes(chunk, mode: FileMode.append);
    }

    return Response.ok('Upload done');
  }

  return Response(400, body: 'No good parts');
}
```

also saw this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSkD3y9HMro&t=996s) and tried:

```
FutureOr<Response> _store(Request request) async {
  List<int> dataBytes = [];

  await for (var data in request.read()) {
    dataBytes.addAll(data);
  }

  String boundaryHeader = request.headers['content-type']!;
  String boundary =
      boundaryHeader.split('=')[1].replaceAll(r'-', '').replaceAll(r']', '');
  final transformer = MimeMultipartTransformer(boundary);
  final uploadDirectory = './upload';

  final bodyStream = Stream.fromIterable([dataBytes]);
  final parts = await transformer.bind(bodyStream).toList();

  for (var part in parts) {
    print(part.headers);
    final contentDisposition = part.headers['content-disposition'];
    final filename =
        RegExp(r'filename="([^"]*)"').firstMatch(contentDisposition!)!.group(1);
    final content = await part.toList();

    if (!Directory(uploadDirectory).existsSync()) {
      await Directory(uploadDirectory).create();
    }

    await File('$uploadDirectory/$filename').writeAsBytes(content[0]);
  }
}
```

I just cant seem to do it right. I end up getting the image on the server i believe because i can see the bytes stored in the variables that got the data from request.read() but then i dont know how to use mime properly and the videos and code that i see seem outdated, i end up having to custom the code because many times the code they use has none defined methods and such.

if someone could point me in the right direction i would appretiate alot. thanks

Comment: Did you try using: https://pub.dev/packages/shelf_multipart